# MvvmCross close fragment from ViewModel

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am writing an android app. I have a MainView, that is of MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity type, and it manages fragments. In ViewModel of a fragment, that is currently shown, i call Close(this), to show previously shown fragment, but nothing is happening.

I use existing MvxFragmentsPresenter. And for testing, i have created a copy of this presenter, and under debug, checked that ChangePresentation, and Close methods are called, and CloseFragment(viewModel) is called, but nothing happens. And in output i cannot see any errors.
After close attempt it outputs:

> [0:] mvx:Diagnostic: 34.91 Requesting presentation change 12-13
>   07:14:01.438 D/Mono    ( 4912): Assembly Ref addref
>   MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.AppCompat[0xe8017220] ->
>   System.Core[0xdd8db900]: 26

Currently to achieve the desired behavior, i simply call OnBackPressed() in fragment view code-behind, but i think that is awfull:

```
public override void OnResume()
{
    var closeButton = Activity.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.close_button);
    closeButton.Click += (s, e) =>
    {
        Activity.OnBackPressed();
    };

    base.OnResume();
}
```

But on iOS app this Close method works as expected.

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the good point made by Stupidus, the working close method looks like:

```
public override bool Close(IMvxViewModel viewModel)
{
    OnBackPressed();
    return base.Close(viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

To make the Close function work for me, I've had to override the Close method in MvxCachingFragmentCompatActivity to this:

```
    public override bool Close(IMvxViewModel viewModel)
    {
        CloseFragment(viewModel.GetType().Name, Resource.Id.content_frame);
        Finish();
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Unfortunately that is not suits in my case.Finish() closes the activity, but i want only to close fragment. And CloseFragment doesn't close it. But you helped me to find more concise solution.